# Void merge sort method java

Tags: java, sorting, merge, mergesort

So, my computer science teacher has told me to make every method here void, except for copyPartArray. I have no idea how to do this, when I try, the sort simply fails.

```
public static ArrayList<String> mergeSortHelper(ArrayList<String> a) {
    int mid = a.size() / 2 - 1;
    if (a.size() <= 1)
        return a;
    return merge(mergeSortHelper(copyPartArray(a, 0, mid)),
            mergeSortHelper(copyPartArray(a, mid + 1, a.size() - 1)));
}

public static void mergeSort(ArrayList<String> a) {
    ArrayList<String> x = mergeSortHelper(a);
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        a.set(i, x.get(i));
    }
}   
    public static ArrayList<String> merge(ArrayList<String> a,
        ArrayList<String> b) {
    ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>(a.size() + b.size());
    int aCount = 0;
    int bCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size() + b.size(); i++) {
        if (aCount > a.size() - 1) {
            for (int j = bCount; j < b.size(); j++) {
                x.add(b.get(j));
            }
            break;
        }
        if (bCount > b.size() - 1) {
            for (int j = aCount; j < a.size(); j++) {
                x.add(a.get(j));
            }
            break;
        }
        if ((a.get(aCount)).compareTo(b.get(bCount)) < 0) {
            x.add(a.get(aCount));
            aCount++;
        } else {
            x.add(b.get(bCount));
            bCount++;
        }
    }
    return x;
}

    public static ArrayList<String> copyPartArray(ArrayList<String> a, int s,
        int e) {
    ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = s; i <= e; i++) {
        x.add(a.get(i));
    }
    return x;
```

I have tried to change my mergeSort to:

```
    public static void mergeSort(ArrayList<String> a) {
    int mid = a.size() / 2 - 1;
    if (a.size() <= 1)
        return;
    mergeSort(copyPartArray(a, 0, mid));
    mergeSort(copyPartArray(a, mid + 1, a.size() - 1));
    merge(a, copyPartArray(a, 0, mid),
            copyPartArray(a, mid + 1, a.size() - 1));
}
```

and get rid of the mergeSortHelper all together.

Now I have:

```
    public static void mergeSort(ArrayList<String> a, int start, int end) {
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    if (a.size() <= 1)
        return;
    mergeSort(a, start, mid);
    mergeSort(a, mid + 1, end);
```

how would I incorporate my merge method into this?

Comment: your teacher is killing the spirit of immutability :(

Answer (score 0):

`copyPartArray` is going to make a copy of the array so that's no good, your lecturer wants you to pass the array by reference and then also pass in the start/end (or start/length) integers. Try doing something like this:

```
public static void mergeSort(ArrayList<String> a, int start, int length) {
    // refer to 'the array' as a[start] to a[start + length]
}
```

`a` will be passed by reference which means you don't need a return value.

So I would change your methods to take a `start` and `length` and get rid of `copyPartArray` all together, you can do your merging in-place on the one array.

I use this method in [my blog post on Quicksort](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/algorithm-quicksort.html).

Comment: ok now i have ' public static void mergeSort(ArrayList<String> a, int start, int end) {
  int mid = (start + end) / 2;
  if (a.size() <= 1)
   return;
  mergeSort(a, start, mid);
  mergeSort(a, mid + 1, end);' how do I incorporate my merge method into this?

Comment: Well you'll be "merging" two sections of the array that will always be adjacent to each other. So you want your merge to perform an in-place sort from `start` to `end`. Something like this:`mergeSort(a, start, mid); mergeSort(a, mid + 1, end); merge(a, start, end);`